# Dell Inspiron 14z laptop vs Dell inspiron 14z ultrabook

Tags: dell

Just wanted to know if both of these are fully compatible with Ubuntu?
If only specific versions of Ubuntu are compatible, then which ones?

http://www.dell.com/ca/p/inspiron-14z-5423/pd

http://www.dell.com/ca/p/inspiron-n411z/pd

Matters I am more concerned about are:

1) Affect on battery life for both?

2) Dual boot without the need to re-install Windows (don't want to use pirated copy) on a separate partition? I can definitely re-partition using partition Magic/EaseUS.

3) Also, I would not prefer keeping my OS's on SSD (in case of 14z ultra-book)

It would be a great help, as I am considering to buy one of these with prime reason of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Dell laptops are compatible with Ubuntu. Infact, both are certified by Ubuntu.

You can see the complete list of Ubuntu certified Dell hardware by visiting this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Dell/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Netbook

Comment: How is the battry life on Ubuntu? I have heard that it reduces to almost half. But from my experience on a ubuntu running netbook earlier, it should increase, as ubuntu manages the resources much more efficiently than Windows does.

Comment: It reduces because the support for the Graphic Card is not good enough. But if you have a nvidia graphic card and you install `bumblebee` package, the battery life would be good.

Comment: it comes only with Intel® HD Graphics 3000 or AMD Radeon HD7570M 1GB.
What can be expected in future Ubuntu distros/updates?

Comment: I'm not sure of AMD, but nvidia has announced that it'd officially support Linux.